# Rails on Heroku and node.js on linode?

Tags: node.js, heroku, dns, websocket

I'm creating an app that uses Rails to serve webpages and node.js/socket.io to facilitate real-time communication. While Heroku can run node.js it can't run websockets, thus I'm going to place the node.js app on linode and the rails app on Heroku.

My question:

In terms of DNS and cross domain issues how would I do this? For instance can I create an A Name record that points 'domainname.com/websockets' => linode and 'domainname.com' => heroku?

Comment: why not install rails on linode?

Comment: I may have to do that. I was hoping to reduce the number tasks for getting everything up and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebSockets security model is not based on same-origin policy. This means that you should not have any cross-origin issues when using WebSockets.

Comment: Unfortunately socket.io falls back to flash sockets and then polling if the client doesn't have websocket support.

Comment: That is also possible with flash sockets and ajax (through CORS or JSONP), and this is in fact implemented by socket.io. It works cross-origin. See the FAQ: http://socket.io/#faq